# Why did the Google DNS stop responding to my ping requests?

Tags: dns, firewall, ping, ipv6

I’m sending regular pings to a few DNS servers to be alerted when networking issues occur.

A few days ago, the Google DNS stopped responding to my pings on IPv6 (2001:4860:4860::8888, screenshot below). Also the alternative address (2001:4860:4860::8844) isn’t responding anymore. The IPv4 addresses (8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4) are working fine.

This is the same from all hosts on my network, including the router.

However, the server is still responding to actual DNS requests (i.e. `dig @2001:4860:4860::8888 google.com` works fine).

Could it be that Google is blocking ICMP from my IP address because I’ve been spamming it with too many pings? Or should I reach out to my provider to see if they are blocking something?

[image: IPv6 packet loss]

Comment: Tried `ping -6 2001:4860:4860::8888`, and it also failed with "PING: transmit failed. General failure." This server might not be available for some reason.

Comment: Blocking ping requests can be done to prevent IP flooding or DOS attacks. This can be done either at the server or through the ISP. I doubt that you are being specifically targeted.

Comment: maybe because you got google with your pings?

Comment: @harrymc Hmm, interesting. It works for me from other machines outside my network (i.e. a cloud server or my mobile broadband).

Comment: Your whole local network might possibly have been blocked because of an excessive number of pings from your part of the world (and mine).

Comment: Now it’s working fine again. Let’s for for how long!

Comment: The Google DNS servers are DNS servers, not ping servers; they *may* respond to pings, but depending on it seems like a bad idea. Are you at least pinging slowly (e.g. one per minute or so)?

Comment: @GordonDavisson I’m sending four pings per minute. From what I see, it’s a widespread practice to ping well-known DNS servers to ensure the connection is working properly. Is this discouraged?